# Make a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog() update?

Tags: java, joptionpane

I need to make a message dialog with JOptionPane that auto refreshes every second in java, for example a message dialog that display the numbers from the 1 to 100 in 100 seconds, I'm new at programming so I tried it making a cycle like this

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class example{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n = 1;
        while(n<=100){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, n);
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem: It makes alot of windows, and doesn't refresh the number, and I need only one message dialog.

Comment: Why don't you use `JDialogue` instead? it will give you better control

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104259/updating-message-in-joptionpane

Comment: Read the [basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) ...

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it that way as the line:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, n);
```

will cause a new dialog to be created each time it is executed. Instead you should extend `JDialog` and add a field for the increment and then execute the code that increments it using a `SwingWorker`.

Answer (score 0):

In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104259/updating-message-in-joptionpane) you can view another sort of post about this. If you check out the [JOptionPane Documentiation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) you can see all it's methods with parameters.

Another thing that you could do, is create your own JDialog with specific methods to update some text.