# create a custom dialog from a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to create a dialog from a JPanel, the problem I am encountering is that the Dialog class and the JOptionPane class which are the main dialog classes I read about use templates (an example of this is your "text" and then a cancel and a confirm button). I want to create a custom dialog that contains my JPanel. I Essentially want to display the entire JPanel in screen without making a new JFrame or reusing the existing one.

thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to use a top level container, you could look at using a CardLayout: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html where your dialog is one of the cards, and you `show` that card when the dialog should be visible.

Comment: Create a factory class to meet your needs - JOptionPane is surprisingly flexible if you’re willing to dig into it

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried to do this with  JOptionPane but my JPanel doesn't fit in the dialog gui. even if I resize it it will be put in the bottom of the screen where you can't even see it. I guess what I want is something like the JFileChooser dialog.

Comment: We’d really need a [mcve]

Comment: A `JDialog` is a top-level container, just like a `JFrame`.  You add one or more `JPanels` to the default `BorderLayout`.  When you create your own `JDialog`, you are responsible for creating any `JButtons` that you need,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most part `JOptionPane` is extremely flexible, for example, starting with something as simple as...

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello world");
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(32f));
        add(label);
    }

}
```

I can do...

[image]

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new TestPane());
```

Ah, but wait, you probably don't want the icon, so instead you can do something like...

[image]

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new TestPane(), "Hello", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

... what do you mean, you want custom options?!  Well, okay, `JOptionPane` can handle that as well...

[image]

```
String[] options = new String[]{
    "options",
    "your",
    "are",
    "These"
};

int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, new TestPane(), "Hello", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[3]);
if (result >= 0) {
    System.out.println(options[result]);
}
```

Now, with a little bit of thought and effort, you could also:

- [Close a `JOptionPane` automatically after a specified timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979504/closing-a-runnable-joptionpane/22979571#22979571) (and another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104259/updating-message-in-joptionpane/15104319#15104319))
- [Control the button state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334931/disable-ok-button-on-joptionpane-dialog-until-user-gives-an-input/14335083#14335083), based in input from the dialog (and a slightly improved [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591089/joptionpane-passing-custom-buttons/14591165#14591165))

`JOptionPane` is a good option, but it's not the only option you have.  You could roll your own "factory" (like `JOptionPane`) that did all the heavy lifting of building a `JDialog`, generating the buttons/options and handling user input (on those actions)